# How can I store a complaint made by a user in my admin panel by django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

what do I write in my views.py and forms.py to store the complaints by a user:
[image]

This is how my site looks and this is where the users can input complaints. How can i save those complaints to later display, edit or delete them accordingly. How can I save those complaints in form of list in the admin panel.

models.py:

```
class Complaints(models.Model):
user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE, null = True, blank=True)
title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
description = models.TextField(null=True, blank= True)
highpriority = models.BooleanField(default=False)
document = models.FileField(upload_to='static/documents')

def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

What do I write in my views.py and forms.py to do this. Please help me. The basic function is to accept complaints so that associated people can receive it and resolve the comlpaints accordingly. How do I make the views and forms so that we can accept these complaints and store them somewhere accordingly?

template

```
<form class="" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="form-control col-lg-10 comp-title-field">{{form.title}}</div>
            <p class="desc">Description</p>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary preview-btn">Preview</button>
            <div class="Descr ">{{form.description}}</div>
            <button type="file" name="myfile" class="btn btn-secondary attach-btn"><i class="fas fa-file-upload"></i> Attachment</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary save-btn" value="submit"><i class="fas fa-save"></i> Save</button>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please check below and do minor changes according to your logic
#forms.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
import your model

class ComplaintForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Complaints
        fields = ['title', 'description', 'highpriority', 'document']
```

views.py

```
import your form
def view_name(request):
    user = request.user
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ComplaintForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=False)
            form.user = request.user
            form.save()

            return render(request,your_template_path,ypur_context)
        return render(request,your_template_path,ypur_context)
    else:
        form = ComplaintForm()
        return render(request,your_template_path,ypur_context)
```

Comment: I tried this but this gives `The view accounts.views.NewComplaint didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.` error after inputing the complaint

Comment: yes, the issue was form.is_valid() not handled proprely

Comment: I type in the complaint, but it is not getting updated or saved in the admin panel

Comment: I added in my template as well... please check if there is something wrong there